# TypeError: can't concat JpegImageFile to bytes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, eyed3

I'm trying to use pillow to download an image and then give that image to eyed3 to use as album art, but I get the following error:

`TypeError: can't concat JpegImageFile to bytes`

```
        response = requests.get(album_art_url)
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
            audiofile = eyed3.load(f"{self.current_song_name}-{self.current_song_url}.mp3")
            audiofile.tag.images.set(type_=3, img_data=img,
                                     mime_type="image/jpeg",
                                     description=None, 
                                     img_url=None)
            audiofile.tag.save()
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: You are passing a PIL/Pillow image as `img_data`. You need to either just pass the URL or the bytes that make up the image... according to the docs I found... https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eyed3/id3/tag.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, based on answer here [How to set thumbnail for mp3 using eyed3 python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668113/how-to-set-thumbnail-for-mp3-using-eyed3-python-module)

```
import eyed3
import urllib.request

audiofile = eyed3.load(f"{self.current_song_name}-{self.current_song_url}.mp3")

audiofile.initTag(version=(2, 3, 0))  # version is important
response = urllib.request.urlopen(album_art_url)
imagedata = response.read()
audiofile.tag.images.set(3, imagedata, "image/jpeg", u"cover")
audiofile.tag.save()
```